# Change picture when holding down click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

I have a code that I am experimenting with. I want the image to change when being held down by a click and to go back to its original state when I release the click. It is not changing at all here.

JS:

```
$('src').on('mousedown mouseup', function mouseState(e) {
    if (e.type == "mousedown") {
        this.setAttribute("src", 'rustb.png')
    } else {
        this.setAttribute("src", 'rust.jpg')
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<img src="rustb.png" id="click" value="Click" />
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: You need to use $(' img.classname') or $('img') instead of src

Comment: `$('src')` is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Your selector gets nothing , you need to select the element / class / ID

`$('img'/'.imgClass'/'#imgId')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try direct `Mouse events` like below and use valid selector.

```
$( "img" )
  .mousedown(function() {
    $( this ).prop("src", 'rust.jpg');
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    $( this ).prop("src", 'rustb.png');
  });
```